the x and y positions of the window are always 0
I was working on the code on a laptop, when I had access to a PC, I transferred all the code to it, but it does not work the way it works on a laptop, my window should move when holding down the left mouse button, but it does not work on a PC, although the system costs the same, when I display the values ​​of x and y, it always gives me 0, even if I entered them manually
x: 50
y: 50

Component.onCompleted: {
    console.log(x, " ", y)
}

Outputs:
qml: 0   0

Full code:
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects
import "../resources" //Colors //Sizes

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow

    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    x: 50
    y: 50

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log(x, " ", y)
    }

    maximumWidth: Sizes.maxWindowWidthSize
    maximumHeight: Sizes.maxWindowHeightSize
    minimumWidth: Sizes.minWindowWidthSize
    minimumHeight: Sizes.minWindowHeightSize

    flags: Qt.Window | Qt.FramelessWindowHint // Отключение стандартного обрамления окна

    property int previousX // переменная хранящая X зажатого курсора
    property int previousY // переменная хранящая Y зажатого курсора

    property int lastWidthSize: Sizes.minWindowWidthSize // переменная хранящая последнюю не максимальную ширина окна
    property int lastHeightSize: Sizes.minWindowHeightSize // переменная хранящая последнюю не максимальную длину окна

    property real lastWindowX: mainWindow.x // переменная хранящая последее положение окна по X
    property real lastWindowY: mainWindow.y // переменная хранящая последнее положение окна по Y

    function changeLastWindowX() // изменить последнюю позицию по x
    {
        lastWindowX = x
    }

    function changeLastWindowY() // изменить последнюю позицию по y
    {
        lastWindowY = y
    }

    function changeLastWidthSize() // изменить последнюю ширину
    {
        lastWidthSize = width
    }

    function changeLastHeightSize() // изменить последнюю длину
    {
        lastHeightSize = height
    }

    onWidthChanged: { // записываем последнюю позицию по x и не максимальную ширину при её изменении
        if(width != Sizes.maxWindowWidthSize)
        {
            changeLastWidthSize()
            changeLastWindowX()
        }
    }

    onHeightChanged: { // записываем последнюю позицию по y и не максимальную длину при её изменении
        if(height != Sizes.maxWindowHeightSize)
        {
            changeLastHeightSize()
            changeLastWindowY()
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: toolBar
        width: parent.width
        height: Sizes.toolBarHeight
        color: Colors.toolBarColor
        z: 1

        layer.enabled: true
        layer.effect: DropShadow {
            anchors.fill: parent
            transparentBorder: true
            verticalOffset: 4
            radius: 4
            color: Colors.dropShadowToolBarColor
        }

        Button {
            id: closeButton
            anchors.right: toolBar.right
            width: 34
            height: 34

            Image {
                source: "qrc:/resources/img/CloseApplication.svg"
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                width: 34
                height: 34
            }

            background: Rectangle {
                color: Colors.toolBarDefaultButtonColor
            }
        }

        MouseArea { // перемещение окна
            anchors.fill: parent

            onPressed: {
                mainWindow.previousX = mouseX
                mainWindow.previousY = mouseY
                console.log(mainWindow.x, " ", mainWindow.y)
            }

            onDoubleClicked: {
                if(isMaximized())
                {
                    restoreWindow()
                }
                else
                {
                    maximizeWindow()
                }
            }

            onPositionChanged: {
                movingWindow()
            }

            function isMaximized() // проверка на максимальный размер приложения
            {
                return mainWindow.width === Sizes.maxWindowWidthSize && mainWindow.height === Sizes.maxWindowHeightSize;
            }

            function restoreWindow()  // сузить окно для прошлого состояния
            {
                mainWindow.setWidth(mainWindow.lastWidthSize);
                mainWindow.setHeight(mainWindow.lastHeightSize);
                mainWindow.setX(mainWindow.lastWindowX);
                mainWindow.setY(mainWindow.lastWindowY);
            }

            function maximizeWindow()  // растянуть окно на максимум
            {
                mainWindow.setWidth(Sizes.maxWindowWidthSize);
                mainWindow.setHeight(Sizes.maxWindowHeightSize);
            }

            function movingWindow() // установка окна в нужнрое положение по x, y и запоминаем их
            {
                mainWindow.setX(mainWindow.x + (mouseX - mainWindow.previousX))
                mainWindow.setY(mainWindow.y + (mouseY - mainWindow.previousY))
                mainWindow.changeLastWindowX()
                mainWindow.changeLastWindowY()
            }
        }
    }

    MouseArea { // изменение размера top
        height: Sizes.toolBarMouseAreaSize
        z: 2

        anchors {
            top: parent.top
            left: parent.left
            right: parent.right
        }

        acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton

        cursorShape: Qt.SizeVerCursor

        onPressed: {
            mainWindow.startSystemResize(Qt.TopEdge)
        }
    }

    MouseArea { // изменение окна bottom
        height: Sizes.toolBarMouseAreaSize

        anchors {
            bottom: parent.bottom
            left: parent.left
            right: parent.right
        }

        acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton
        hoverEnabled: true

        cursorShape: Qt.SizeVerCursor

        onPressed: {
            mainWindow.startSystemResize(Qt.BottomEdge)
        }
    }

    MouseArea { // изменение окна left
        width: Sizes.toolBarMouseAreaSize

        anchors {
            left: parent.left
            top: parent.top
            bottom: parent.bottom
        }

        acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton
        hoverEnabled: true

        cursorShape: Qt.SizeHorCursor

        onPressed: {
            mainWindow.startSystemResize(Qt.LeftEdge)
        }
    }

    MouseArea { // изменение окна right
        width: Sizes.toolBarMouseAreaSize

        anchors {
            right: parent.right
            top: parent.top
            bottom: parent.bottom
        }

        acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton
        hoverEnabled: true

        cursorShape: Qt.SizeHorCursor

        onPressed: {
            mainWindow.startSystemResize(Qt.RightEdge)
        }
    }
}

the problem is in the movingWindow() function, everything else works correctly

You call movingWindow every time the mouse moves, but you are setting the window position to its current position plus the difference between the current mouse and the original mouse-when-clicked.  That means the deltas will accumulate as the mouse gets further away.

@TimRoberts maybe even if I don’t calculate the displacement correctly, then even when I manually set x and y it displays 0

OT: when posting code, please ensure that you either translate or completely remove code comments written in languages different than English.

But onCompleted only gets called after initialization, right?  It doesn't show you anything dynamically.

If you intend to move the window, you can use startSystemMove. Check this answer.
